# Returning struct * stored in fifo queue as void * (returning it by several functions)

Tags: c, struct, void-pointers

Hello I have a little problem with void * used to make code more generic. 
I have written fifo queue (using linked list underneath) that is storing any data that can be casted to void * (i.e. struct * as void *).

Now I have function that retrieves this data back. But the problem is that struct that has 3 fields is returned with only first field filled and others 2 are empty (was filled when placed in the queue).

All functions like back(), unwrap'_data_from_node'() and fifo_dequeue() returns this data as void *.  What is more odd is that void * can be casted to struct * in fifo_dequeue() and it will contain all fields filled with data, while when returned from fifo_dequeue() the same pointer returned has only one field filled (1st field), and two are empty, nil.

```
   void *fifo_dequeue(fifo_queue_t *fifo, size_t *data_size) {

    doubly_linked_node_t *node;
    size_t tmp_size;
    void *tmp_data;
    void *data;

    // get data and its size from the last node in the queue
    if((node = back(fifo->queue)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "back: queue is empty!\n");
        data_size = NULL;
        return NULL;
    };
    tmp_data = unwrap_data(node, &tmp_size);

    /** HERE I tested casting data to struct test_t and it works properly **/
    task_t *task;
    task = (task_t *) tmp_data;
    int task_size = sizeof(task);

    // copy retrieved data
    data = malloc(tmp_size);
    memcpy(data, tmp_data, tmp_size);

    // remove the last node in the queue
    //pop_back(fifo->queue);

    if(data_size != NULL) *data_size = tmp_size; // return size of data through pointer argument
    return data; /** OUTSIDE this pointer casted to struct task_t has empty fields **/
}
```

The underlying method removing node from linked list while making pop_back();

```
   void remove_node(doubly_linked_list_t *list, doubly_linked_node_t *old_node) {

    // if node to delete unspecified return error
    if (old_node == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Node to delete is empty!");
        return;
    }

    // if node to delete is the only left on the list make empty list
    if (old_node->next == old_node) // or old_node->prev = old_node
    {
        list->head = list->tail = NULL;
    } else {
        old_node->prev->next = old_node->next;
        old_node->next->prev = old_node->prev;

        if(old_node == list->head) list->head = old_node->next;
        if(old_node == list->tail) list->tail = old_node->prev;
    }

    free(old_node->data); old_node->data = NULL;
    free(old_node); old_node = NULL;
}
```

Comment: I suppose the problem is with memcpy it copies just pointer to struct stored in data and not contained fields pointers. So first element can be maintain but remaining are lost. I need to copy as pop_back removes and deallocates data from node in linked list

Comment: `int task_size = sizeof(task)` <-- that can't be right: `sizeof *task` is I think what you want, and at any rate: `sizeof` returns `size_t`, not `int`. Also `task_t *task; task = (task_t *) tmp_data;` looks ugly. Why not `task_t * task = tmp_data;`. No need for the cast. It's a clean, easy to read one-liner

Comment: Yeah but this is task_t is only test code. I place it to show that when it is cased to real type task_t *(of structure)  it has all fields populated but when I just operating on void * (generic type) and I am copying it and then returning as void * then I am losing fields even if later to the same cast. I think it is the effect of memcpy void * not the real type. Bu I don't know how to compensate this issue. I don't want to lose generics in my underneath fifo queue and linked list, also don't want to make mess by passing additonal type casters to make this copy type-safe.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `sizeof()`

You only take the pointer size in this line

```
int task_size = sizeof(task);
```

after that, not enough data is copied.

You need to malloc and copy the whole struct by the struct size:

```
int task_size = sizeof(task_t);
```

Comment: yeah but data stored in linked list under fifo_queue are pointers (void * data)

Comment: if you only want to return the pointer, go ahead. No need to copy anything. But if you want to copy the whole struct, you need to copy by the struct size.

Comment: yeah but problem is that I want to return void * from fifo_dequeue() in order to fifo queue could store generic typed data and be reusable. I could return just this tmp_data pointer and not mamcpy() it but there is another problem as before there is pop_back() which removes node from fifo_queue (linked list) and then it free() this pointer so I want to make a copy of it. Maybe I should remove this deallocation of data

Comment: I think that removing this data deletion while pop node from list while be the best solution making it possible to keep all data structures generic. I will need to deallocate data later I think. But also have doubts what if someone will be just pop_back() without retrieving data on such linked list and this data could be never deallocated

Comment: if you dont want the queue to know anything about the payload. You have to add the ability to register a free function (distructor) for each node. Think about a situation where memcpy is not enough. You might need a string in the struct,